# Is there any way to get event on date selection for angularjs material calender

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-material

I was trying to implement a calendar, on which when I select date, I want an event to be fired and get the control. I am only able to get the date selected and not able to get that event. 
https://material.angularjs.org/1.1.6/api/directive/mdCalendar

I tried going through the library for the above calender, 
https://github.com/angular/material/blob/master/src/components/datepicker/js/calendar.js

Here, I see an event being emitted, how can I listen to this event? md-calendar-change

```
 /**
   * Sets the ng-model value for the calendar and emits a change event(md-calendar-change).
   * @param {Date} date
   */
  CalendarCtrl.prototype.setNgModelValue = function(date) {
    var value = this.dateUtil.createDateAtMidnight(date);
    this.focus(value);
    this.$scope.$emit('md-calendar-change', value);
    this.ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(value);
    this.ngModelCtrl.$render();
    return value;
  };
```

Answer (score 2):

The best way to react to date selection is to use the `ng-change` directive:

```
<md-calendar ng-model="birthday" ng-change="onSelect(birthday)">
</md-calendar>
```

For more information, see

- [AngularJS ng-change Directive API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange)